# How to remove ticks from multiple images in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```py
def plot_random_grid(img,num_rows=2,num_cols=2,width=None, height=None):
    

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(num_rows, num_cols)

    seed=1

    for i in range(num_rows):
        for j in range(num_cols):

            axs[i][j].imshow( random_crop(img,width=width,height=height,seed=seed))
            
            axs[i][j].set_title("Seed: %s (100x100)" % (seed))
            
            seed += 1
            plt.axis("off")
            
plot_random_grid(img_cv,num_rows=2,num_cols=3,width=100,height=100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `tick_params` or `set_(x or y)ticks`:

```py
rows = 2
cols = 4
fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows,cols)

for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        axs[r,c].plot([1,2,3])
        axs[r,c].tick_params(axis  = 'both', bottom= False, left  = False,
                             labelbottom = False, labelleft   = False)
```

Or...

```py
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        axs[r,c].plot([1,2,3])       
        axs[r,c].set_xticks([],[])
        axs[r,c].set_yticks([],[])
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to just but labels on the bottom left graph for example you can do this:

```py
rows = 2
cols = 4
fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows,cols)

for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        axs[r,c].plot([1,2,3])
        if r == 1 and c == 0:
            continue
        else:            
            axs[r,c].tick_params(axis  = 'both', bottom= False, left  = False,
                                 labelbottom = False, labelleft   = False)
```

Output:

[image]

Also, if you want to remove the space between them (like for your above image) you can use `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)`:

```py
rows = 2
cols = 4
fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows,cols)

for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        axs[r,c].plot([1,2,3])      
        axs[r,c].tick_params(axis  = 'both', bottom= False, left  = False,
                             labelbottom = False, labelleft   = False)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

[image]